# Не работает .click()

Tags: javascript

Нужно в расширении для хрома, при нажатии на заданную клавишу кликать по кнопке в веб приложении. Пробовал сменить цвет фона кнопки, сменить название кнопки - это работает, а вот именно клик - нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

мой код:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 69) {
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-standard');  
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
      elem[i].click();
    }
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен авто-клик на `JavaScript`, без участия `Jquery` и сторонних библиотек.
Можно сделать так:

```js
Element.prototype.clicker = function(func, params) {
  params = {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window , ...params
  };
  let cancel = !this.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(
     'click',
     params
  ));
  if(!cancel) {
     'function' === typeof func && func(this);
  }
};

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 69) {
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-standard');  
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
      elem[i].clicker((elm) => {
         elm.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      });
    }
  }    
};
```

```html
<div class="btn-standard">1</div>
<div class="btn-standard">2</div>
<div class="btn-standard">3</div>
<div class="btn-standard">4</div>
<div class="btn-standard">5</div>
```

Для передачи координат в `params` можно передавать `{clientX:100, clientY:100}` - подробнее можно глянуть тут: [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

Answer (score 0):

Функция `click()` является функцией jQuery. Импортируйте его и тогда всё заработает.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 69) {
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-standard');  
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
      elem[i].click();
    }
  }    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn-standard' id='1' onclick='document.getElementById("1").innerHTML ="Ok"'>Nope</button>
<button class='btn-standard' id='2' onclick='document.getElementById("2").innerHTML ="Ok"'>Nope</button>
<button class='btn-standard' id='3' onclick='document.getElementById("3").innerHTML ="Ok"'>Nope</button>
```